# backbon.js mobile pack sample application

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app, forcetk

I am referring sample application for mobile pack for backbone.js

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/04/build-mobile-web-apps-with-backbone-js-and-the-salesforce-platform.html

Looking at the code for save / destroy functions, 
Could someone help me understand how the save/destroy function works behind the scene ?
How destroy deletes the contact record from Salesforce ?
what happens behind the scene such that record gets deleted in salesforce when destroy function is called ?
is forceTK or entity.js coming into picture here ?

some insight would be very helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the blog post does a good job of explaining this at a high level but let me explain in a bit more detail.

1. The first key thing is to understand the `Model` definition

   ```
       app.Contact = Backbone.Force.Model.extend({ type: 'Contact',
       fields: ['Id', 'Name', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'LastName']});
   ```

This creates an object of type `Contact` and sets the field definition as specified in the `fields` section

2. Next you need to understand how the various events are associated to the Contact entity

   ```
                 events: { 'change' : 'change',
                 'click .save' : 'save',
                 'click .destroy': 'destroy'
               },
   ```
3. `app.router` holds an instance of your app router. The `save()` method saves a new record with the data from your form into the model and the `app.router.navigate()` method redirects your app control back to the Contacts list.

`{`

```
    //...
    save: function(){
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function(model) {
                // Setting trigger to true reloads the contact list - we want
                // the latest data from Salesforce!
                app.router.navigate('contacts', {trigger: true});
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error saving');
            }
        });
        return false;
    },//...
    });</pre></code>
```

Setting `trigger` to true means that the list is refreshed from Salesforce and it includes the newly created record.

4. The destroy() method removes the record from the model and fires a call to Salesforce to delete the record and then refreshes the list similarly

`destroy: function(){
      this.model.destroy({
        success: function() {
          app.router.navigate('contacts', {trigger: true});             
        },
          error: function () {
            alert('Error deleting');
          }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });`

To answer your other question

> is forceTK or entity.js coming into picture here ?

This is being used internally but you're not invoking any explicit calls with forceTk for the above methods.